# Oauth2-proxy - 404 error when redirecting to upstream url (Django application web page)

Tags: django, keycloak, custom-error-pages, oauth2-proxy, upstream

I'm trying to protect a Django application with oauth2-proxy

**In the oauth2-proxy configuration:** (version 7.2.1 or 7.3.0)

When the upstream url is set to something like this: --upstream="http://127.0.0.1:8000"
the redirection works fine. (and it returns a home page I have defined in the application )

But, if I use an upstream like this: --upstream="http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello"
it returns 404 error instead of the hello page that is also defined in the application

The page http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello is working fine when invoked directly and it returns **"GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 136**

So I would say it is not a problem with the page.

**This is the command line I'm using:**

```
oauth2-proxy.exe ^
    --http-address=127.0.0.1:4180 ^
    --email-domain=* ^
    --cookie-secure=false ^
    --cookie-secret=adqeqpioqr809718 ^
    --upstream="http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello" ^
    --redirect-url=http://127.0.0.1:4180/oauth2/callback ^
    --oidc-issuer-url=http://127.0.0.1:28081/auth/realms/testrealm ^
    --insecure-oidc-allow-unverified-email=true ^
    --provider=keycloak-oidc ^
    --client-id=oauth2_proxy ^
    --ssl-insecure-skip-verify=true ^
    --client-secret=L2znXLhGX4N0j3nsZYxDKfdYpXHMGDkX ^
    --skip-provider-button=true
```

When the oauth2-proxy succeeds to redirect (--upstream="http://127.0.0.1:8000"), I get the page and the following output:

**This is the output for the oauth2-proxy:**

```
[2022/09/08 10:52:06] [proxy.go:89] mapping path "/" => upstream "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
[2022/09/08 10:52:06] [oauthproxy.go:148] OAuthProxy configured for Keycloak OIDC Client ID: oauth2_proxy
[2022/09/08 10:52:06] [oauthproxy.go:154] Cookie settings: name:_oauth2_proxy secure(https):false httponly:true expiry:168h0m0s domains: path:/ samesite: refresh:disabled
[2022/09/08 10:57:01] [oauthproxy.go:866] No valid authentication in request. Initiating login.
127.0.0.1:54337 - 9bbfcf75-da91-487a-a55e-40472e4adb23 - - [2022/09/08 10:57:01] 127.0.0.1:4180 GET - "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27" 302 380 0.001
127.0.0.1:54337 - e0d8ed12-e4dd-4da6-9fbb-cf689fc53f8f - mail@gmail.com [2022/09/08 10:57:09] [AuthSuccess] Authenticated via OAuth2: Session{email:mail@gmail.com user:93547bcc-2441-414a-9149-c7533c4f5d23 PreferredUsername:testuser token:true id_token:true created:2022-09-08 10:57:09.789934 -0300 -03 m=+303.019857301 expires:2022-09-08 11:02:09.7839238 -0300 -03 m=+603.013847101 refresh_token:true groups:[role:offline_access role:uma_authorization role:default-roles-testrealm role:account:manage-account role:account:manage-account-links role:account:view-profile]}
[2022/09/08 10:57:09] [session_store.go:163] WARNING: Multiple cookies are required for this session as it exceeds the 4kb cookie limit. Please use server side session storage (eg. Redis) instead.
127.0.0.1:54337 - e0d8ed12-e4dd-4da6-9fbb-cf689fc53f8f - - [2022/09/08 10:57:09] 127.0.0.1:4180 GET - "/oauth2/callback?state=ahuKzCYr7jR4P4mmjniIt67TttZKyxGv4mLfEwKlQio%3A%2F&session_state=86ac9bd1-9756-4916-83e9-ec0496b5b767&code=df3940e5-58f5-49ac-a821-5607f0f2faae.86ac9bd1-9756-4916-83e9-ec0496b5b767.cd30a162-8e4d-4a2d-bff6-168e444aed92" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27" 302 24 0.029
127.0.0.1:54337 - d58ace6e-afe9-4737-9b12-dbc17fdd0ca2 - mail@gmail.com [2022/09/08 10:57:09] 127.0.0.1:4180 GET / "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27" 200 138 0.005
```

**On the Django side I get:**

```
**"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 138**
```

---

---

When the oauth2-proxy fails to redirect --upstream="http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello"), I get the following output:

**This is the output for the oauth2-proxy:**

```
[2022/09/08 10:33:58] [proxy.go:89] mapping path "/hello" => upstream "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello"
[2022/09/08 10:33:58] [oauthproxy.go:148] OAuthProxy configured for Keycloak OIDC Client ID: oauth2_proxy
[2022/09/08 10:33:58] [oauthproxy.go:154] Cookie settings: name:_oauth2_proxy secure(https):false httponly:true expiry:168h0m0s domains: path:/ samesite: refresh:disabled
[2022/09/08 10:37:20] [oauthproxy.go:866] No valid authentication in request. Initiating login.
127.0.0.1:53615 - 54c0f3d8-b3c0-4d48-8353-fe69be0e4500 - - [2022/09/08 10:37:20] 127.0.0.1:4180 GET - "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27" 302 380 0.001
127.0.0.1:53615 - 0bec934e-05a3-4cc8-9306-fffc28597c8f - mail@gmail.com [2022/09/08 10:37:28] [AuthSuccess] Authenticated via OAuth2: Session{email:mail@gmail.com user:93547bcc-2441-414a-9149-c7533c4f5d23 PreferredUsername:testuser token:true id_token:true created:2022-09-08 10:37:28.6527488 -0300 -03 m=+210.486252601 expires:2022-09-08 10:42:28.6468518 -0300 -03 m=+510.480355601 refresh_token:true groups:[role:offline_access role:uma_authorization role:default-roles-testrealm role:account:manage-account role:account:manage-account-links role:account:view-profile]}
[2022/09/08 10:37:28] [session_store.go:163] WARNING: Multiple cookies are required for this session as it exceeds the 4kb cookie limit. Please use server side session storage (eg. Redis) instead.
127.0.0.1:53615 - 0bec934e-05a3-4cc8-9306-fffc28597c8f - - [2022/09/08 10:37:28] 127.0.0.1:4180 GET - "/oauth2/callback?state=nox0LM3fIlVU1kamoLBaktByeLCcIWiBvRLdHFIuhd4%3A%2F&session_state=808c0654-c9e7-4593-b5dc-95d3231438ea&code=e220414d-e949-4e2d-8d33-55de96f8f5d4.808c0654-c9e7-4593-b5dc-95d3231438ea.cd30a162-8e4d-4a2d-bff6-168e444aed92" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27" 302 24 0.024
127.0.0.1:53615 - 9454773f-cade-46fe-870f-70d09fc49ffb - mail@gmail.com [2022/09/08 10:37:28] 127.0.0.1:4180 GET - "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27" 404 19 0.000
```

**On the Django side I get:**

Nothing. As the Django app is never reached and so there are no logs.

Could you please help me find out what could be happening? I will really appreciate it!!

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the application, as the pages work fine when invoked directly.
If it is a mistake in my oauth2-proxy command line/configuration, I would appreciate someone points me to the error, so I can correct it.

Otherwise, any hint would also be much appreciated.

The only thing I've noticed in the logs of oauth2-proxy is that no matter what I put in the --upstream, the final GET (I think it is the redirection to the upstream) is as follows: GET - "/" ... it is the same in both attempts, and it only succeeds in the first one, because it matches the [proxy.go:89] mapping path "/"

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was giving the 404 error, was that the configuration --upstreams points to a url to which the proxy is going to pass the request once authenticated, but it is not going to redirect to that address unless you specifically ask for it in the original request.

So the correct way of making the request is http://127.0.0.1:4180/hello, which is including the whole path to the endpoint you want to reach. (instead of for example http://127.0.0.1:4180 )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using environment variables, beware the upstream environment variable has a 'S' at the end of it.
Namely: `--upstream http://myfqdn:myport` should be `OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAMS=http://myfqdn:myport`